# How to split up a nested ternary statement inside a .map function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I have a code like

```
      obj.map((u) =>
        u.members ? u.members : u.id ? u.id : u.member_id, 
      )
```

I need to split it up b/c eslint doesn't like nested ternary operators. I know logically it should be something like that but not sure what the syntax is suppose to be inside the map function

```
          .map((u) =>
            if(u.members ){
              u.members ;
            }
            else{
              if(u.id){
                u.id;
              }
              else{
                u.member_id;
              }
            }
          )
```

Comment: http://converter.website-dev.eu/

Comment: The function in map i just like any function. Meaning it can have many lines, and it can return value.

Comment: Since the logic is fairly straightforward you might simplify to `u.members || u.id || u.member_id` and forego using a ternary at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like

```js
.map((u) => {
  if(u.members ){
    return u.members ;
  }
  else if(u.id){
    return u.id;
  }
  else{
    return u.member_id;
  }
});
```

As the callback function of map has become multi-line, you can wrap that in `{}` and thus write it like any other method including return statements.

Comment: I have a similar question, how would I rearrange the `id` below?

      `const memberNodes = members.map((member) => ({
        id: member.assigned_members ? member.assigned_members : member.member_id ? member.member_id : member.id,
        title: member.member_name,
        shape: 'image',
        level: i,
      }));`

putting something like this gives syntax errors.
`if( member.assigned_members ){
          id: member.assigned_members,
        }
        if(member.member_id){
          id: member.member_id,
        }else{
          id:  member.id,
        }`

Comment: It might be difficult to answer in the comments. Can you raise a different question so that I can provide the answer in a clear manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do following things:

- Wrap the arrow function with `{}`
- Return values from function

Your code would look something like:

```
.map(u => {
  if(u.members)
    return u.members;
  else if(u.id)
    return u.id;
  else       
    return u.member_id;         
  })
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I think the other guy answered first!